# Low quality texture paint

Tags: texturing

[image]

The brush I made seems to be ok but When I paint, it shows up as a low quality mess. The brush is on the left and the result is on the right. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the image large enough?

Comment: It's 1150 x 1171 px

Comment: yes but how is your unwrap?

Comment: Everything works fine now. It was my base color texture resolution.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Maybe write an answer with some details

Comment: To change base color resolution in texture painting, in the texture slot, select either material or single image. Click the + and select from the drop down list. You will be given an option to change the resolution. Mine was too low by default. There is nothing wrong with my unwrap.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the information